# How can I remove apps from my "cloud"?

Tags: amazon-kindle, amazon-kindle-fire

When I delete an application from my Kindle Fire, it remains in the "cloud" in case I ever want to re-download them. Is there any way I can remove/disown these apps so they don't show up in the cloud?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove the book/app from your cloud, you'll need to visit [Visit amazon.com/myk](http://amazon.com/myk). Log into your account and find the book/app. Click the "actions" link to the right of the title. Under it you'll have the option to delete it permanently. After you do so, you'll have the repurchase the book if you want to read it again.